# indenting outputLabel

Tags: visualforce

Using pageBlocSectionItems and need to indent rendered child items. Tried to use spacing but getting formatting errors. The highlighted label is what I need to indent. [image]

Added the following style class but now the label is shifted too far right:[image]

[image]

```
.col4{
width:200px;
height: auto;
float: left;
padding-left: 10px;
text-align:left;
color:purple;
}

<apex:tab label="Workers Comp" name="tab1" id="tab1" >
<apex:outputPanel Style="width:100%;" layout="block">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="LOB_WC1" title="My Content Section" columns="2" showHeader="false" >

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="PEO or Employee Leasing Op in business?" for="account__name" StyleClass="col1"  />
                        <apex:actionRegion >                    
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Account_Summary__c.WC_PEO_Employee_Leasing_Op_in_business__c}" id="account__name" StyleClass="col2" >
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="LOB_WC1" / > 
                        </apex:inputField>
                        </apex:actionRegion>                        
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >
                        <!-- <apex:outputLabel value="Comment 1" for="account__site" style="float: left;text-align: right;width:20px;color:blue;" /> --> 
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Account_Summary__c.WC7_Comment__c}" id="account__site" Style="width:100%;height: auto;float: left;text-align: left;color:purple"  /> 
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  


                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" rendered="{!CONTAINS(Account_Summary__c.WC_PEO_Employee_Leasing_Op_in_business__c,'PEO') }" >
                    **<apex:outputLabel value="PEO Claims Handling"  **StyleClass="col4"**  rendered="{!CONTAINS(Account_Summary__c.WC_PEO_Employee_Leasing_Op_in_business__c,'PEO')}"/>** 
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account_Summary__c.WC_PEO_Claims_Handling__c}" style="color:blue;" rendered="{!CONTAINS(Account_Summary__c.WC_PEO_Employee_Leasing_Op_in_business__c,'PEO')}"/> 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col" rendered="{!CONTAINS(Account_Summary__c.WC_PEO_Employee_Leasing_Op_in_business__c,'PEO')}" >
                        <!-- <apex:outputLabel value="Comment 1" for="account__site" style="float: left;text-align: right;width:20px;color:blue;" /> --> 
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Account_Summary__c.WC8_Comment__c}" id="account__site" Style="width:100%;height: auto;float: left;text-align: left;color:purple"  rendered="{!CONTAINS(Account_Summary__c.WC_PEO_Employee_Leasing_Op_in_business__c,'PEO')}"/> 
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>            
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:tab>
```

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the preview?

Comment: Just added the screenshot .

Comment: Have you tried simply adding `padding-left` or `margin-left` to the `col1` class?

Comment: @rickmac By default the labels appear right aligned so something in your `col` or `col1` css is causing them to be aligned differently. I could show an example but the answer would just be an image to back up the comment. If you want to brut force it put the `&nbsp;&nbsp;` right before the `outputLabel` tag not inside it

Comment: Can't prefix the outputpanel on pageblocksectionitem. You get the error; 'may have no more than 2 child components.' The CSS is a good option. Trying that now.

Comment: @rickmac Doh, forgot about that. And wrapping the elements in an outputPanel will further complicate the issue

Comment: @Santanu Boral your styles for outputLabel got me thinking.  I flipped the CSS statements setting padding-left: 10px; before setting text-align: left; which worked. Updated code and screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore the option to leverage **apex:panelGrid**. Please find the sample below.

**Scenarios**

Sometimes it is necessary to display more than 4 columns where fields are usually `<apex:inputField>` or `<apex:outputField>`, where `apex:PageBlockTable` with `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` are not suitable.

**Visualforce**

```
<style>
    .colStyle1 { width: 10%;padding-left:5px; text-align:left; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:5px;}
    .colStyle2 { width: 10%;text-align:left; padding-left:5px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px}
    .colStyle3 { width: 10%; text-align:left;padding-left:5px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px}
    .colStyle4 { width: 10%; text-align:left;padding-left:5px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px}
                .colStyle5 { width: 10%;padding-left:5px; text-align:left; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:5px;}
    .colStyle6 { width: 10%;text-align:left; padding-left:5px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px}
    .colStyle7 { width: 10%; text-align:left;padding-left:5px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px}
    .colStyle8 { width: 10%; text-align:left;padding-left:5px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px}
</style>
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
      <apex:panelGrid columns="8" border="0" styleClass="tableStyle" width="100%" columnClasses="colStyle1,colStyle2,colStyle3,colStyle4,colStyle5,colStyle6,colStyle7,colStyle8">
                                                <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">Forecase_Revenue1__c</apex:outputLabel> 
                                                <apex:outputfield value="{!bk.Forecase_Revenue1__c}"></apex:outputfield>
                                                <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">Forecase_Revenue2__c</apex:outputLabel>
                                                <apex:outputfield value="{!bk.Forecase_Revenue2__c}"></apex:outputfield>
                                                <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">Forecase_Revenue3__c</apex:outputLabel>
                                                <apex:outputfield value="{!bk.Forecase_Revenue3__c}"></apex:outputfield>
                                                <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">Forecase_Revenue4__c</apex:outputLabel>
                                                <apex:outputfield value="{!bk.Forecase_Revenue4__c}"></apex:outputfield>
                                                <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">Forecase_Revenue5__c</apex:outputLabel>
                                                <apex:outputfield value="{!bk.Forecase_Revenue5__c}"></apex:outputfield>
                                                <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">Forecase_Revenue6__c</apex:outputLabel>
                                                <apex:outputfield value="{!bk.Forecase_Revenue6__c}"></apex:outputfield>
                                                <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">Forecase_Revenue7__c</apex:outputLabel>
                                                <apex:outputfield value="{!bk.Forecase_Revenue7__c}"></apex:outputfield>
                                                <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">Forecase_Revenue8__c</apex:outputLabel>
                                                <apex:outputfield value="{!bk.Forecase_Revenue8__c}"></apex:outputfield>       
      </apex:panelGrid>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
```

**Expected output**

[image: panel grid]

Comment: Thanks @Santanu Boral. I may try going the panelGrid route.